# Get SharePoint Groups (not AD groups) using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Is there a method to retrieve SharePoint Groups using Microsoft Graph?

I can get Azure Directory groups using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` but what I'm looking for are SharePoint Groups.

I could get a `SiteCollection` using `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{id}` but I couldn't seem to get the SharePoint Groups in site collection.

Answer (score 3):

This is not very easily accessible in just the Microsoft Graph. If you had some access to the SharePoint API, you could get the GUID from the "User Information List" - which seems hidden from the Microsoft Graph at this time.  That SharePoint API call would be 

`GET HTTP https://sometenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists?$select=title,id&$filter=Title%20eq%20%27User%20Information%20List%27`

Once you have that GUID for that list you could do the Graph call: 

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site id}/lists/{list ID from the SharePoint API}/items`

That will get you the full list of members, including groups. This is still a hack since the groups you'd have to filter by contentType/name eq 'SharePointGroup' - which seems buggy in Graph Explorer anyways. Trying to programmatically access that, would be difficult at this time.

Comment: Thank you! Will try it out.

Comment: This will list users and groups (and you can filter by ContentType per Louis' post.  However, the membership of the groups does not appear to be available within the list items (fields).  If anyone knows the final piece to those details, it would be very helpful!

Comment: hi, it seems to be still an open point. I also need to read the membership information. Hopefully anybody has a solution now.